# angular js: array value returned by a function in separate blocks

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

making a program in which i need to work with angular js array, i need to display angular js array element returned by a function in a good manner. like first  contains first element,second  contains second element and so on... and use of function is mandatory to perform some future tasks.
thanks in advance
for example:-

first attempt:-
first element= 23
second element = 45

second attempt:-
first element= 20
second element = 15

third attempt... fourth attempt and so on

```
      <head>
        <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>

      </head>
      <body><div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

           <div ng-repeat='selecting in selects'  ng-init="selecting.var1=selecting.var2=a='';"> 

        <input type="text" ng-model="selecting.var1">
        <input type="text" ng-model="selecting.var2">

      <button type='button' ng-click='remove(selecting)'>Remove</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type='button' ng-click='add()'>Add</button>
       </div>
       <p>{{ x = test()}}</p>
      <!-- first block -->
      <!-- second block and so on--> 
      <li ng-repeat="x in b" style="list-style:none">
     first attempt=  {{ x.first  | number:0  }} <br>
     second second= {{ x.second | number:0}}
      </li>
      </div>

      <script>
         var app = angular.module("plunker",[]);
         app.controller("MainCtrl",['$scope',function($scope){


              $scope.test = function()
              {
                     var result=1,id2,a,b;
                     $scope.result1 = [{}];

                         angular.forEach($scope.selects, function(value)
                         { // loop over array to process all items
                            a = value.var1;
                            b = value.var2;
                            alert(a);

                        $scope.result1.push({name:$scope.selecting.var1});
                            //myarray = {"first":a,"second":b}
                            //a['first','second'] = (a,b);
                                return result1;
                        })
              }
              $scope.selects = [{}]; // default 1 sets
            // functions to ADD/Remove --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              $scope.add = function() 
              {
                        $scope.selects.push({});
              }
              $scope.remove = function(item) 
              {
                        angular.forEach($scope.selects, function(value, key) 
                        {
                            if (value == item) 
                            {
                                $scope.selects.splice(key, 1);
                            }
                        });
             }
            // functions to ADD/Remove ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        }]);
      </script>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: i mean i am passing text box value to a function..and we can generate multiple textbox. and function will return array every time with value of first row of textbox..and then values of 2nd row of textboxes and so on..

Comment: pasting code in fiddle in a moment

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nitishkaushik/z6m78m2o/7/

Comment: Could you please re-name your variables to something that might help us understand what you are trying to do.   `ng-repeat="x in b"` is just so unclear. And it seems  `b` is not even defined on the `$scope` so it will not render.

Comment: oh sory i was doing it as experiment,dats why i use temporary name,just renaming in fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea what you are trying to achieve in your `test()` function but if you are just trying to display the content of your then model there doesn't seem to be any need to create a function for that: Angular keeps the model in sync for you, that's one of the main selling points of the framework.

Is that what you are trying to achieve?

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/YnhGthfcUzarYET0hEu8?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>

  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat='textBoxes in textBoxGroups' > 

      <input type="text" ng-model="textBoxes.textBoxOne.value">
      <input type="text" ng-model="textBoxes.textBoxTwo.value">

      <button type='button' ng-click='remove($index)'>Remove</button>

    </div>

    <div>
      <button type='button' ng-click='add()'>Add</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type='button' ng-click=doSomething()>Do Something</button>
    </div>

    <h3>Text Box Group Model</h3>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>$index</th>
          <th>TxtBox1</th>
          <th>TxtBox2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='textBoxes in textBoxGroups'>
          <td>{{$index}}</td>
          <td>{{textBoxes.textBoxOne.value}}</td>
          <td>{{textBoxes.textBoxTwo.value}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

     <h3>Char Count: {{charCount}}</h3>

      <h3 ng-show="processedData.length">Data After Some Process</h3>


    <table ng-show="processedData.length">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>$index</th>
          <th>Original</th>
          <th>Updated</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='data in processedData'>
          <td>{{$index}}</td>
          <td>{{data.original}}</td>
          <td>{{data.updated}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>


  </div>




<script>

var app = angular.module("plunker",[]);

app.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){




  $scope.textBoxGroups = [ {

      textBoxOne: { value: '' },
      textBoxTwo: { value: '' }

    } ];


   $scope.add = function(){
    $scope.textBoxGroups.push({

      textBoxOne: { value: '' },
      textBoxTwo: { value: '' }

    });
  }

  $scope.remove = function($index){

    // just pass in the $index of the element you want to remove
    // and splice it out

    $scope.textBoxGroups.splice($index, 1);

  } 

  $scope.doSomething = function(){

    $scope.processedData = [];
    $scope.charCount = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.textBoxGroups, function(textBoxGroup){
      $scope.processedData.push({
        original: textBoxGroup.textBoxOne.value,
        updated: textBoxGroup.textBoxOne.value.toUpperCase()
      });

      $scope.charCount += textBoxGroup.textBoxOne.value.length;
    });



  }

}]);

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: exactly sir ..this is the same output i need

Comment: but i need it using a function,i want to send textbox values in function and then i have to perform some operation on each row value and then i have to save result in array index like my_array("sum1","sum2","sum3");

Comment: Why do you need the function. You have the synced values right there in the `textBoxGroup` variable. What do you mean 'send values' send them where?. Just loop over the model, do any work you need on each element then put any results in a new array. To display the new array just have it defined as a property on your `$scope`where you can access it in a template.

Comment: actually am doing a complex project (complex for me) . if u dont mind posting that website link https://www.getbannerman.com/book-security
in this page in SUMMARY block,, date and time calculation of each box is showing... something like this is need of my work

Comment: I have updated the answer to show one way you can do some other process on your model. If you feel the answer has helped you could you please consider up-voting it and or accepting it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: ok sir.. thanks for your effort and your code will work as a guide for me... i will make my code output using your code... thanks again :)